# What are the essential Starcraft 2 maps for training?

Tags: starcraft-2

I've seen a number of mentions to several maps that help improve your Starcraft 2 gameplay.  Two I've heard often are Yet Another Build Order Trainer (YABOT) and the Multitasking trainer.  *(I'll post them as answers - marked as community wiki, I'm not rep whoring!)*

What other training maps are available?  One answer per post please.

Comment: Well it looks like you got my two favorite.

Comment: One brilliant map was the Macro or Die series but they seem to have stopped working with Patch 1.5. :(

Answer (score 15):

#### [Multitasking Trainer](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=124983)

> On the bottom left side of the map is your starting position and right above that is a terran base. Your purpose is to create an army and destroy the enemy base. The terran will attack and/or drop you at several points in time depending on the difficulty setting. There is also a neutral unit at the island on the right side that you have to rescue and bring back to your base.
>
> The tricky part is that in the top right side of the map you control a probe that is constantly being chased by a zergling. So you need to manage your base, defend the attacks and save the neutral unit, all while microing the probe to keep it from dying. This is a great way to practice not only your early game scouting but also your multitasking and hotkey usage.

Comment: This might sound weird but the thing that helped me the most with the MT Trainer was playing a lot of mine sweeper.  If you're trying for time it really forces you to make very quick decisions and remember minor facts.

Answer (score 11):

#### [Yet Another Build Order Tester (YABOT)](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=128752)

> This project is a series of standard 1v1 Blizzard maps adapted to include a sophisticated build order testing system. You are given 7 minutes to execute the chosen build while keeping up worker production and creating the largest army possible. You will need to pay some attention to Micro because the AI will send attack waves depending on what build order you choose for the computer. At the end of the 7 minutes, you are given a score which tells how well you executed the build. Also included is a "Freestyle" build, which monitors your play and displays the build order you performed.

Comment: [Author demonstration of YABOT](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kyz7dRKX_Ag&hd=1) on YouTube. The current version looks to be more customizable than your answer suggests.

Comment: @Lee I just copied the description from the page.  This post is community wiki; feel free to add to or change its content.

Comment: we need yabot for lotv. please. someone read this comment and do it