# What are the most popular multi-player maps?

Tags: starcraft-2

I am an experienced StarCraft player, now past 12 missions in the campaign. Before going to multi-player games I would like to look at the maps that are often played.

Could you please list the most popular ones?

Comment: duplicate : http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7233/which-starcraft-2-maps-are-played-most-often/7286#7286

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When playing ladder, you are exposed to all maps in the 'map pool'.  If you want to practice games on maps you'll play in the ladder, practice with the maps listed below.   However, there are a few maps that are significantly more popular than the others and often played in custom games and tournaments:

Lost Temple, Metalopolis, Xel'Naga Caverns, Scrap Station, and Steppes of War are very popular for 1vs1 games.

**Battle.net Map Pool.**

**1v1**

Blistering Sands (2)
Jungle Basin (2)
Scrap Station (2)
Steppes of War (2)
Xel'Naga Caverns (2)
Shakuras Plateau (4)
Lost Temple (4)
Metalopolis (4)
Delta Quadrant (4)

**2v2**

Arid Wastes (4)
Discord IV (4)
Monlyth Ridge (4)
Scorched Haven (4)
Twilight Fortress (4)
Tarsonis Assault (4)
Tempest (8)
High Orbit (4)
War Zone (4)

**3v3**

Arakan Citadel (6)
Colony 426 (6)
Dig Site (6)
Frontier (6)
Monsoon (6)
Quicksand (6)
The Bio Lab (6)
Ulaan Deeps (6)
Typhon (6)

**4v4**

Extinction (8)
High Ground (8)
Lava Flow (8)
Megaton (8)
Outpost (8)
Sand Canyon (8)
Toxic Slums (8)

**FFA**

Kulas Ravine (4)
Lost Temple (4)
Metalopolis (4)
Tectonic Rift (6)
Quicksand (6)
Abyss (8)

Answer (score 2):

Map popularity should be some what different dependent on your opponents race.

Certain maps favor certain races more then others. You can use this information to veto out maps that are weak to the race play. You can also study them to better understand what makes them weak and adjust your play style when you play on those maps.

Also if you meant popular Custom Maps they can be found here:
http://www.sc2mapster.com/popularity/

Answer (score 1):

To see which maps are in the current ladder map pool, you can go to "Multiplayer", select a match up type you are interested in (like 1v1 or 2v2) and then click the "Map Preferences" button next to "Find Match".

This will show you a list of the currently used maps including small pictures and short descriptions.