# What are the Terran's best and worst 1v1 maps?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-terran

In [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11395/starcraft2-what-are-popular-multi-player-maps), I asked what maps are good for multiplayer Starcraft matches. Now, after getting some more experience, I'm wondering: what are good/bad maps for Terran 1v1 play?

I would very much appreciate if you could provide any reference or your own explanation for why each map is good/bad for Terran.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include a link to the question you're referring to.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11395/starcraft2-what-are-popular-multi-player-maps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I like theory as much as the next guy, this is an area where I have to side with statistical analysis.

Assuming a balanced map implies a 50% win chance, then a map which deviates from this by a statistically significant amount can be called: imbalanced.  We can control for Racial imbalance by using the current win rates; maps that deviate from that rate are considered a factor in imbalance beyond racial imbalance.  To further help control for skill level I'm only going to consider top ranked matches, so we don't have to worry about mistaken matches between Bronze/Diamond players.

For my data source I will use [TLPD](http://www.teamliquid.net/tlpd/sc2-korean/maps).

Here are [the calculations](https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0Am57dGT4LkjRdC05MzNoSUZ1VEphWi1famtkU1phalE&hl=en&authkey=CIaHwJwF).

From this table, the most likely imbalanced maps are:

1. PvZ Metal
2. ZvT Blistering Sands
3. TvZ Jungle Basin
4. PvT Xel'Naga
5. ZvT Shakuras

All of these maps have P values of less than .01 (many scientific articles require P < .05)

Thus a Terran should feel comfortable against a Zerg on Jungle Basin, but uncomfortable vs Zerg on Shakuras and Blistering Sands, and uncomfortable against Protoss on Xel'Naga.  It's worth noting that Terran are favored in all maps, but that these are the only ones that deviate significantly from the standard favoring.

Note: Many of the PvZ maps did not have enough games to provide for a low enough P value.

Comment: I'm all for statistical analysis myself, and I love the data you have compiled here. I'm even willing to accept the assertion that "no race has statistically better players than the other". However, racial imbalance is something that is historically a point of contention, and I don't see this instance as any different. I looked at overall win-loss [based on your data](https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0AqO85YkpOnJEdGd2bjl2VGNuTXpFVEJYcWlKQU1sRmc&hl=en&authkey=CI-gsvQL).

Comment: The results suggest one of two things: severe map favoritism or racial imbalances. I posit that it's a little of both, so statistical analysis must be taken with a grain of salt. 

I think it's interesting to note that, overall, Terran win most of their matches, whereas Zerg seem to be the noted underdog. The closest mixed-race matchup appears to be Terran vs. Protoss. Of course, that was all off-topic, but it's interesting nonetheless. :)

Comment: @Shaun actually we can control for Racial Imbalance by only looking at the deviation from those numbers!

Comment: @Shaun I added the new numbers back in

Answer (score 7):

**Short Answer**

tzenes provides some statistical analysis in [his answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15526/what-are-the-terrans-best-and-worst-1v1-maps/15550#15550). The information in this answer is based largely on theory.

Based on the criteria in the long version of this answer, here are some maps that exhibit many of the qualities that are said to favor Terran by a notable margin:

- 1v1 maps

  - Agria Valley
  - Steppes of War
- Larger maps

  - Delta Quadrant
  - Discord  IV
  - Lost Temple
  - Red Stone Gultch
  - Scorched Haven
  - Tarsonis Assault

**Long Answer**

There is [a thread on Team Liquid's forums](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=142802) wherein this was discussed. Here is some of the Terran-specific feedback from that thread:

- **Rush distance** - *Short rush distances* allow Terran to put pressure on other races early, especially vs. Zerg. Large rush distances neutralize the benefit of being able to rush an opponent before they can defend their entrance.
- **Entrances** - *Maps with good choke points at their entrance* favor Terran due to their ability to wall off early. *Maps that also do not have back door entrances* in combination with the good choke entrance favor the "Terran Turtle" even more. Maps with multiple entrances to the main base tend to allow opposing races to exploit their mobility more.
- **Choke points** - *Maps that have one main path to the other bases* favor Terran more due to their ability to wall off and defend against sieges. With multiple paths, the mobility of other races combined with the stretching of resources to defend the multiple attack vectors complicate things for Terran.
- **Cliffs**

  - *Cliffs that allow Terran mech to abuse choke points extensively* are an added bonus. Without large cliffs, seige tanks become less effective as a defensive measure.
  - *Large cliff ridges at each base favor* Terran due to a more difficult time defending against reaper harassment. Smaller cliffs limit your ability to harass early on.
- **Expansions**

  - *Island expansions* are typically easier and cheaper for a Terran player to establish.
  - *2nd and 3rd expansions being close to the main or on an island* benefit Terran due to the ability to effectively wall up all land-based access to the expansions via one choke point. Expansions that are further away tend to present more of a difficulty for Terran to protect and reinforce due to decreased mobility.