# How to play custom build-anything map in Starcraft 2 with others?

Tags: starcraft-2

I see players in replays and screen-casts that have maps where they create all kinds of buildings and units very quickly. I'd like to try some scenarios with a friend of mine.

- Is there a custom map where I can create anything and have no supply cap?
- Can I play this map as a custom game with them online?
- Will it have a replay when we're done?

Comment: Usually these maps (unit testers) are one player, as both players spawning whatever they want isn't really that fun.  YABOT (build-order tester) is multiplayer, though.  See [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7069/what-are-the-essential-starcraft-2-maps-for-training) for a list of training maps - and if you find a good unit tester *(the only ones I know of were stopped working after the beta)*, add it to the list!

Comment: The point was to set up something ridiculous, like send 400 SCVs at him. Any way to set that up?

Comment: Can you link a replay or cast showing the functionality you want? I've never heard of a map like that used for multiplayer.

Comment: I'd settle for it in single-player. I've never seen it, just was hoping I could do it with a friend, but I'd still accept an answer that was single player only.

Answer (score 3):

"Unit Tester Online" is a very good unit testing map:

[image: Map details]

With this map you can easily create different unit combinations to test them. There are many options (like different terrain, enabled upgrades,...) to customize the battle you want to test.

[image: Unit setup]

[image: Battle result]

You can play this map together with other people online, but it will not create replays.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom game and type "Unit Tester Online"

The map you're looking for should be called that, there's a lot of different versions though and it will be hard to find the best one because Battle.net 2.0 is terrible. Bookmark it when you do.